# Add-in not available in shared mailbox

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I was using an add-in with a shared mailbox.
After doing some work. I Can't be used now.

Details are described below.

1. Open a shared mailbox Using the "Open another mailbox" option setting.
2. Click Get Add-in to open the dialog screen.
3. Remove the add-in from the "admin-managed"
4. "Error AccessDenied" Is displayed when adding an add-in.
   There are also problems with official add-ins(etc...My Templates )

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open Another Mailbox" scenario is not fully supported on Outlook Web Add-ins as of now. We are working on our document update to reflect this status. You can request for this support by creating an entry in our Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas page